# Kid's TV show like "Rescue Heroes" where a character had a glowing half-sphere gauntlet on their right hand that would power their vehicles

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember a toy I got years ago, probably 11+ years ago, that had a DVD for a kid's animated TV show for it. The animation was exactly like the first generation *Rescue Heroes*. The toy/show character had a glowing half-sphere gauntlet on their right hand that would power their vehicles.

The episode had a nuclear weapon(?) and the main characters had to stop it from going critical and blowing up the toy.

The guy looked like he was in the army and in the show he had a jeep-looking thing.

Comment: [Eon Kid](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1001471/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My brother and I were just thinking of this show this evening and I finally found it: Major Powers and the Star Squad.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain how this matches the description given in the question?

Comment: Per the above please could you [edit] this to explain how it matches? Alternatively you could also edit in a basic synopsis/description of the show with key elements that match the details in the question. Note if you edit in a description from elsewhere please include a link to where it came from and also indicate what is a quote with quote markdown i.e. a > at the start of the relevant paragraphs.